# Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Fechas - Parte 1/3

Tags: discusión

Esta es la primera vez que estoy organizando algo de este estilo, la actividad es una reunión de una hora a 1 hora y media aproximadamente, un compartir entre todos una taza de chocolate o café, con temas de conversación variados (los que salgan de momento) manteniendo la buena vibra, el respeto y la armonía.

Para esta reu navideña de fin de año, por favor, dejen de lado temas que generen discusiones como que si el uso de X tecnología es mejor que Y tecnología, que si un framework A o si un framework B o si es mejor hacer todo desde cero sin framework; en el mundo del desarrollo hay de todo y discusiones de este tipo son efectivas cuando se hacen entre miembros del mismo equipo del desarrollo que tienen un cliente en común para atender.

Se podría compartir experiencias en el mundo del desarrollo, anéctodas, cosas curiosas, proyectos interesantes que hayamos realizado, cosas aburridas que hayamos tenido que hacer, los retos más complejos que enfrentamos, las features más "sin sentido" que hayan sido solicitadas, visión a futuro de la carrera con esta onda de la inteligencia artificial acercándose tan rápido a la sociedad actual y cualquier otro tema donde se mantenga el respeto, la buena vibra y la armonía.

Ahora bien, la cuenta de Zoom que tengo, tiene una capacidad tope de 100 personas con tiempo de 30 horas para mantener el meeting (solo usaremos 1H - 1H 30M), dudo mucho que se necesite más.

Para cuadrar bien entre todos, es utilizar las respuestas para realizar las votaciones correspondientes por fecha. Por este motivo, habrá 3 preguntas en Meta:

- Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Fecha - Parte 1/3 (Esta publicación)
- [Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Hora - Parte 2/3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5597/822)
- [Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Resultado - Parte 3/3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5606/822)

El resultado, es decir, la parte 3 de "esta serie navideña", la publicaré el día 21 a las 8pm Hora del Pacífico.

Las fechas tentativas son:

- Sábados: 23, 30.
- Domingos: 24, 31.

Las horas tentativas para el inicio, son 4pm, 5pm, 6pm y 7pm hora España, de este modo, en todo hispanoamérica estaremos de día y podremos participar.

Como son 4 horas y 4 días, hay 16 posibles combinaciones, la votación se cerrará el 21 a las 8pm hora del Pacífico, donde tomaré la opción con más votos para el día y la opción con más votos para la hora, hay gente que estará libre y podrá en cualquier hora, otros en cualquier día a una hora en particular y se trata de encontrar ese punto de equilibrio para todos los participantes.

### Para confirmar su participación en esta actividad:

Aparte de realizar las votaciones de fechas y horas, regístrense en el siguiente formulario:

https://forms.gle/XZgk7fPA8RcbqddHA

A los correos descritos les llegará la invitación de Zoom una vez que hayamos definido fecha y hora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Opción Sábado  23.

Todos los que estén participando y estén a favor de esta fecha, un voto positivo.

Comment: muy buena idea, apoyo lo del 23 porque estoy libre amaneciendo el 24 ... 7 PM

Comment: buena voz :D en la otra pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5597/822 están las opciones de zonas horarias disponibles. Realiza la votación en caso no la hayas hecho y de preferencia deja un comentario, como para animar a la comunidad a que se pronuncie. PD: registrate en el link de Google Forms, ahí se enviará el link de Zoom.

Answer (score 1):

### Opción Domingo 31.

Todos los que estén participando y estén a favor de esta fecha, un voto positivo.

Answer (score 0):

### Opción Sábado 30.

Todos los que estén participando y estén a favor de esta fecha, un voto positivo.

Answer (score 0):

### Opción Domingo 24.

Todos los que estén participando y estén a favor de esta fecha, un voto positivo.