# Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Horas - Parte 2/3

Tags: discusión

Ahora tenemos otro escenario para definir, las zonas horarias en todo hispanoamérica.

Este post es la continuación de la pregunta anterior.

- [Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Fecha - Parte 1/3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5592/822)
- Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Hora - Parte 2/3 (Esta publicación)
- [Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Resultado - Parte 3/3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5606/822)

Tengan en mente que las fechas tentativas son:

- Sábados: 23, 30.
- Domingos: 24, 31.

Desde el sitio web https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/ he generado la siguiente captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Importante

Quienes deseen anotarse, vayan a la [primera parte de esta serie](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5592/822) y regístrense en el Google Form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Hora 4pm España

En la imagen se encuentran las zonas horarias equivalentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

### Hora 5pm España

En la imagen se encuentran las zonas horarias equivalentes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

### Hora 6pm España

En la imagen se encuentran las zonas horarias equivalentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

### Hora 7pm España

En la imagen se encuentran las zonas horarias equivalentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]