# Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Horas - Parte 3/3

Tags: discusión

Aloha~ buen día, vamos por partes, primero, las disculpas del caso, era para publicar el día 21 a las 8pm Hora del Pacífico y se me pasó por efecto de los finales del instituto.

Esta actividad de la chocolatada navideña por Zoom, consta de 3 publicaciones en Meta:

- [Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Fecha - Parte 1/3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5592/822)
- [Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Hora - Parte 2/3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5597/822)
- Chocolatada navideña online por Zoom - Resultado - Parte 3/3 (Esta publicación)

### Resultados

Día: Con 5 votos ganó la opción para este **Sábado 23**.

Hora: Con 7 votos ganó la opción de las **4pm Hora España**.

[image: Zonas horarias equivalentes a las 4pm en España]

### Para confirmar su participación en esta actividad:

Regístrense en el siguiente formulario:

https://forms.gle/XZgk7fPA8RcbqddHA

A los correos ingresados en este enlace les llegará la invitación de Zoom.

Si alguien se anima, todavía se puede registrar.
El tema de cuadrar la fecha y la hora ya quedó completado.

Comment: No quería dejar de felicitarte por la iniciativa y motivación que has puesto a la actividad. Muy feliz navidad !!

Comment: ¡Feliz navidad mi buen amigo! Muchas gracias por la buena vibra, ya quedó como experiencia la forma de manejar este tipo de iniciativas: tener un post para acomodar fechas, otro para acomodar las horas donde se vea de manera simple y directa, aquí la herramienta de https://www.worldtimebuddy.com se prestó de maravilla para eso. Finalmente una publicación para mostrar los resultados luego de unos días de votaciones. Conversando con Rubén, creo que haremos esto más seguido, que se anime más gente y vamos 2024 con meetups online!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resultados

Día: Con 5 votos ganó la opción para este **Sábado 23.**

Hora: Con 7 votos ganó la opción de las **4pm Hora España.**