# Encuentros virtuales por zoom cada 2-3 meses

Tags: discusión, meetups

Aloha~ buen día, se acaba de completar la primera semana del 2024. Hace unas semanas se dio la iniciativa de la [chocolatada navideña 2023](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5592/822) por zoom que tuvo buena aceptación para ser la primera vez que se realiza este tipo de actividad, motivo por el cual me animé a redactar el presente post.

### La idea:

Reunirse entre los que deseen para conversar de cualquier tema que se presente, con tal que exista respeto, empatía y buena onda, todo va a ir bien. Se podrían presentar los temas en esta publicación a modo de respuestas y conversar de ellos el día del zoom.

Dependiendo de cómo vaya reaccionando la comunidad y deseen apuntarse, daríamos inicio a la fase de organización que va de este modo:

- **1 Publicación para definir el día**, puede ser sábado o domingo por efectos de comodidad para todo Hispanoamérica unidad.
- **1 Publicación para definir la hora de inicio**, que sería desde las 4pm hora España hasta las 7-8pm hora España.
- **1 Publicación para definir la semana** donde será el evento, aquí hay 4 opciones: el primer fin de semana, el segundo, el tercero o el cuarto.

Personalmente sugiero el segundo o el tercero porque el último fin de semana es cierre de mes y normalmente hay bastante trabajo en distintas empresas, y el primer fin de semana recién estamos iniciando el mes y a veces el estrés viene desde la semana anterior.

### Referencia horaria:

[image: Zona horaria]

**El primer encuentro sería en febrero o marzo**, dependiendo de lo que dicte la mayoría de los interesados.

El medio es por Zoom debido a su simplicidad, seguridad por contraseña y porque en el instituto donde estoy, estoy llevando tutoría con dicha plataforma de pago y hay que aprovecharla.

Gracias por leer hasta aquí, que tengan un buen inicio de semana, vamos viendo qué comentarios, ideas y propuestas salen de esta publicación.

Un abrazo,

Fredy.

### Actualización

- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Día - Organización - Parte 1/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5629/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Hora - Organización - Parte 2/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5632/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Fecha de fin de semana - Organización - Parte 3/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5637/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Resultados - Organización - Parte 4/4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5663/822)

Comment: yo creo que menos de 2 o 3 meses, despues nos enfriamos ...

Comment: ¿Qué tal _encuentros_ en lugar de _reuniones_? _Reunión_ suena a algo formal, y _encuentro_ suena más informal (si es que se busca hablar de temas en general, claro está) :)

Comment: Te tomo la sugerencia @padaleiana, editado.

Comment: No hay que olvidar que la plataforma de chat tiene manera de programar eventos. Podría ser interesante tener a la par de la plataforma de videollamada, en este caso Zoom Meeting, eventos de la plataforma de chat. No tengo mucha experiencia con los eventos de chat, pero hay tiempo para averiguar, por lo pronto me imagino un evento de chat por cada fecha de videollamada. Esto no cambiaría la dinámica de seguridad, sólo sería tener una herramienta mas para promover y compartir cosas, en este caso asuntos específicos a cada *encuentro*.

Comment: en esta ocacion creo mi persona no va a poder participar, tengo mucho trabajo por delante e iniciando nuevos proyectos en temas de salud que son muy delicados. espero les vaya bien en la chocolatada

Comment: Freddy, cuenta conmigo, como siempre. Saludos

Comment: ¿Realmente el objetivo es hablar sobre cualquier tema o hay algún límite? Por ejemplo, sobre Stackoverflow, que solo se hable de programación o tecnología. Me recuerda al café filosófico.

Comment: Vamos a ir planeando el primer encuentro, a ver como sale y cuanta acogida tiene. @fredyfx esperamos por las publicaciones pertinentes.

Comment: @Mateo claro, la idea es conocernos más allá de un avatar y un username. Con tal que haya respeto y la buena vibra se mantenga, todo fresh~