# Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Día - Organización - Parte 1/4

Tags: discusión, meetups

¡Mi pregunta recibió un -1, exijo explicación!
*¿Cómo eh posible ete suceso? ¡No puede ser! Tenemos que llamar al 911, a los Thundercats y utilizar la espada del Augurio ooooohhhhhh!!!*

Bien, ahora que tengo su atención, les presento la continuación de la propuesta :D

### Publicación inicial

[Encuentros virtuales por zoom cada 2-3 meses](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5619/822)

Al momento de redactar esta publicación, han pasado:

- 6 votos a favor.
- 0 votos en contra.
- 8 días.
- 145 visitas.
- 5 personas que han comentado.

Como hay gente con ganas de realizar la actividad, procedemos a habilitar las siguientes áreas:

- Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Día - Organización - Parte 1/4 (esta publicación).
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Hora - Organización - Parte 2/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5632/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Fecha de fin de semana - Organización - Parte 3/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5637/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Resultados - Organización - Parte 4/4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5663/822)

Acomodando las cosas, considero que en 3 semanas podríamos tener todo armado para el primer encuentro virtual de la hermandad SOes 2024.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Voto para el sábado.

Definitivamente los sábados me caen mejor que los domingos para este tipo de actividades.

Answer (score 0):

### Voto para el domingo.

Definitivamente los domingos me caen mejor que los sábados para este tipo de actividades.