# Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Hora - Organización - Parte 2/4

Tags: discusión, meetups

Continuando con la organización de los encuentros virtuales de la hermandad SOes 2024.

### Publicaciones

- [Encuentros virtuales por zoom cada 2-3 meses (publicación inicial.)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5619/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Día - Organización - Parte 1/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5629/822)
- **Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Hora - Organización - Parte 2/4 (esta publicación).**
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Fecha de fin de semana - Organización - Parte 3/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5637/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Resultados - Organización - Parte 4/4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5663/822)

Para el tema de la hora, considerando un buen rango para todo Hispanoamérica unida:

[image: Zona horaria referencial]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 7pm Hora España.

Prácticamente todo Latam estaría en la tarde.

Answer (score 1):

### 4pm Hora España

De este modo, tenemos a casi todo Latam en la mañana y algunos países a mediodía.

Answer (score 1):

### 5pm Hora España.

(Por lo visto, se necesita al menos 30 caracteres para publicar).

Answer (score 0):

### 6pm Hora España

Aquí tenemos a más países de Latam entrando a la tarde y acercándose a mediodía.