# Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Fecha de fin de semana - Organización - Parte 3/4

Tags: discusión, meetups

### Publicaciones

- [Encuentros virtuales por zoom cada 2-3 meses (Publicación Inicial)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5619/822).
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Día - Organización - Parte 1/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5629/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Hora - Organización - Parte 2/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5632/822)
- Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Fecha de fin de semana - Organización - Parte 3/4 (ésta publicación).
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Resultados - Organización - Parte 4/4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5663/822)

Es momento de organizar el número de fin de semana que vayamos a quedar para los encuentros virtuales. Hay meses con 5 semanas, sin embargo, por efecto de practicidad, vamos seleccionado entre 4 opciones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Tercer Fin de semana del mes.

Así de simple, para qué complicarse la vida~

Answer (score 0):

### Primer Fin de semana del mes.

Hay que empezar con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 0):

### Cuarto Fin de semana del mes.

Hay que terminar el mes con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 0):

### Segundo Fin de semana del mes.

Justo celebrando la quincena que pagaron :D