# Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Resultados - Organización - Parte 4/4

Tags: discusión, meetups

Aloha~ buenas madrugadas, espero se encuentren bien.

Al momento de redactar esta publicación, han pasado 3 semanas desde el 16 de enero en zona horaria del Pacífico, tiempo suficiente para acomodar y dejar que la comunidad de SOes realice las votaciones necesarias para tener un resultado democrático.

Antes de seguir, quiero expresarles mi gratitud por la participación que han tenido con esta iniciativa, idea que salió en la sala de chat de SOes (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) originalmente con motivos navideños 2023 y que luego se expandió a "reuniones online" que posteriormente cambió de nombre a  "encuentros online" para que finalmente, por motivos de alegrías en la sala de chat, quedó como "chocolatadas" hahahaha xD!!!

Y bueno, seguimos con la organización, algo sumamente importante que quería dejar para ahora, considerando que los interesados están al pendiente de estas publicaciones, el paso elemental:

### Para completar su participación

Por favor, llenar el siguiente formulario de `Google Forms`, les prometo que sus correos solo serán para invitarles el link de la invitación de Zoom.

https://forms.gle/nJWpubnmn99MdTWYA

**Primera Chocolatada**

- Día: sábado 17 de febrero.
- Hora: 7pm hora España.
- Lugar: Zoom

### Zonas horarias equivalentes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si desean agregarlo directo al calendario, hice un archivo `.ics` listo para importar:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zj0hLZewuEZo-NBuJVOf0ge8pZzCDKtm/view?usp=drive_link

### Propuestas de temas para conversar

- Clásica presentación: nombre y/o nickname, edad o rango de edad, profesión u oficio, país y algún dato que deseen compartir.
- Hobbies.
- Música.
- Cine, series, anime, manga.
- Programación (nada de peleas de lenguajes de programación ni de frameworks por favor).
- Inteligencia Artificial.
- Hardware, IoT.
- Cloud Computing.
- Formas de desconexión de la tecnología.
- Definir si la siguiente chocolatada será en abril/mayo o si lo dejamos a votación en otro post en META.

¿Deseas proponer algo más? Siente la libertad de ponerlo a modo de respuesta, entre todos se puede armar algo bien interesante.

### Vamos con las estadísticas

| Publicación | Vistas | Votos a favor | Votos en contra | Votos mostrados |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Encuentros virtuales por zoom cada 2-3 meses (Publicación Inicial). | 195 | +5 | 0 | 5 |
| Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Día - Organización - Parte 1/4. | 84 | +3 | 0 | 3 |
| Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Hora - Organización - Parte 2/4. | 57 | +1 | 0 | 1 |
| Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Fecha de fin de semana - Organización - Parte 3/4 | 73 | +1 | 0 | 1 |

### Resultados

| Organización | Votos a favor | Votos en contra | Votos mostrados |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Voto para el sábado. | +7 | 0 | 7 |
| 7pm Hora España. | +3 | 0 | 3 |
| Tercer Fin de semana del mes. | +5 | 0 | 5 |

### Curiosidades

- Nadie votó para el domingo.
- En segundo lugar quedó empate para la hora: 4pm y 5pm con 1 voto. Las 6pm quedó fuera con 0 votos.
- Para el fin de semana, ganó por goleada la opción del 3er fin de semana del mes.

### Publicaciones

- [Encuentros virtuales por zoom cada 2-3 meses (Publicación Inicial).](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5619/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Día - Organización - Parte 1/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5629/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Hora - Organización - Parte 2/4.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5632/822)
- [Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Fecha de fin de semana - Organización - Parte 3/4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5637/822)
- Encuentros virtuales por Zoom - Resultados - Organización - Parte 4/4 (ésta publicación).

Comment: Vamos con todo el Power 2.0!!!

Comment: ¡Esa es la actitud @MauricioContreras!